# How to pass integer from MasterViewController to DetailViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are a lot similar questions and answers to this one, but I do not get it working. I want to pass the cellnumber in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (in MasterViewController) to viewDidLoad (in DetailViewController). Here is what I have:

```
    //MasterViewController.m:
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger num = indexPath.row;//cell.tag;

        DetailViewController *Second  = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        Second.number = num;

    }

    //DetailViewController.m:
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        if(number == 0){

//show something
        } else if(number == 1){
    //show something else
            }
        [self configureView];
        }
```

How must I do this?

Comment: you are not pushing the secondViewController, that you are creating in didSelectCellForIndexPath. you just need to do self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController

Comment: Where is your code for Navigation?

Comment: you just need to do [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController];

Comment: The fact that you down voted everyone is not very mature. I suggest you change your attitude towards seeking help, otherwise you're not going to get far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int num = indexPath.row;//cell.tag;
    DetailViewController *detailVC  = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailVC.number = num;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) int number;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
 @implementation DetailViewController
 @synthesize number;

 -(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];         
    NSLog(@"Number:= %d",number);
 }
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: On the line     [super viewDidLoad:animated]; I get the error No visible @interface for 'UiViewController' declares the selector 'viewDidLoad'. What causes this?

Comment: Oh.. It was my mistake. Write this line instead of it.              [super viewDidLoad];

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new instance of `DetailViewController` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. So, when the current instance of `DetailViewController` loads - the values will be nil.

Take a look at this SO answer for more detail explanation: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: why the value is nil ? its not subview

Comment: Because you're creating a new instance of DetailViewController in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. When the actual DetailViewController is loaded from memory it is not the same instance you created in didSelectRowAtIndexPath - that instance no longer exists.

Comment: I think you are totally wrong

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your problem

Answer (score 0):

In `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger num = indexPath.row;//cell.tag;

        DetailViewController *Second  = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNumber:indexPath.row];

    }
```

In `DetailViewController.h` :

```
@property (nonatomic) int number;
- (id)initWithNumber:(int)number;
```

In `DetailViewController.m`

```
- (id)initWithNumber:(int)number
{
   self.number = number;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   if(number == 0){

   } else if(number == 1){

   }

   [self configureView];

}
```